# What are Real World Compass Readings in Android

Tags: android, compass

I will try to be as specific as I can. I am building an AR app for that I need Compass North South East West ( what I think). I am new in android development so I don't know much about it. I am currently Using Unity, and I am confused about the readings which should be used as a real world value, either "True heading" or magnetic Heading ? which one of these corresponds to the real worlds north, south, east, west. and also these values change with orientation of the Phone. is there a way to get back original values.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normal, magnetic compass like this always shows the magnetic heading:

[image]

Magnetic heading is relative to the magnetic North Pole.

True heading is relative to the geographic North Pole.

Magnetic heading almost always differs from true heading due to [magnetic variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_deviation). See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_%28navigation%29#Relationship_between_true_and_magnetic_direction) for further information.

Comment: so which shall I use in android ?

Comment: @Newprogrammer depends on what you want to do with it. If you want to replicate a real world compass, use magnetic. They both have roughly the same amount of hits on github: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=trueHeading&type=Code&ref=searchresults vs https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=magneticHeading&type=Code&ref=searchresults

Comment: alright.. So to replicate real world compass (to get real world NORTH , SOUTH EAST WEST) I would Use magnetic heading.. thanks.. also does orientation of device effects magnetic heading ?

Comment: @Newprogrammer If you mean portrait/landscape orientation, no. If you mean the direction the top of the device is pointing, yes. Magnetic heading IS that direction relative to the magnetic north pole.

Comment: sorry but I am so confused about this. I have posted another question but no one answered. Suppose my device is landscape left and I want to get direction which the back camera of the device is facing Is this Possible or not if yes then can you please explain How ?  if I know that direction I will use that direction to calculate latitude longitude of that direction I am trying to do this ..

Comment: @Newprogrammer I don't know the answer to that question.